# Problemas con header() en una iteracion para comprobar el login

Tags: php

Hola Amigos aquí de nuevo;

Hoy vengo con un pequeño "gran problema" y es que la función header(); me está machacando y no sé bien por qué. Os explico.

Tengo un archivo que se llama validar_login.php que sirve como programa para validar los datos que se recogen del formulario login.php. Bien este código, verifica que el usuario esté registrado y que coincidan los usuarios con las contraseñas (está sin hash las password, por mis pruebas).

Aclarar que en la BD tengo dos usuarios: EVA1 -> 123456 y otra EVA1 -> 5678. 
y otro que es EVA2 -> 12345; con Eva2 no tengo problemas. Sin embargo con EVA1 me da igual una contraseña que otra.

Pues en resumido ahí va mi problema:

Si $usuario y $password coinciden -> Inicia sesión sin problema.
Si $usuario y $password no coinciden -> "echo" me imprime sin problema
Si $usuario y $password no coinciden -> si cambio "echo" por un "header(Location: nueva_sesion.php)" me lleva a la página sin problemas, sin embargo, inserto $usuario y $contraseña correctos en la "nueva pagina" y me dice que no es correcto. Se queda como en un bucle donde ya todo es incorrecto.

Si a la "nueva_sesion.php" en vez de dirigir mi formulario a  (es decir a la misma pagina), ERROR no entra es todo falso. Sin embargo, si  hace lo mismo sin problema.

Probado en incognito y nada. Sin solucion.

Dejo el código de validación:

Gracias Amigos!

```
<?php


try{

//2-conectamos a la base de datos
include("99_connect-db.php");

//1-Almacenamos los datos en variables
$usuario=htmlentities($_POST['usuario']);
$password=htmlentities($_POST['password']);

        echo "$usuario <br>";
        echo "$password <br>";




//preparamos la base de datos
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Almacenamos los datos de la tabla Usuarios
$sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO= :usuario";
$resultado=$conn->prepare($sql);

//Listamos el campo usuario y contraseña
$resultado->execute(array(":usuario"=>$usuario));


//almacenamos el número de columnas que contiene $usuario
$contador=$resultado->rowCount();
echo "Filas: $contador <br>";

if($contador!=0) {

//Transformamos la info de usuarios en un array
while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo "Usuario: " . $registro['usuario'] . " Contraseña: " . $registro['password'] . "<br>";

                if ($usuario==$registro['usuario'] && $password==$registro['password']) {

                    //creamos una sesion
                    session_start();

                    //almacenamos el usuario en una variable superglobal
                    $_SESSION['susuario']=$usuario;

                    //Redirigimos a la pagina de usuarios registrados
                    header("Location: 12_login_correcto.php");

                }  else {
                    header("Location: 02_login.php");

                }

        }

} else {
    echo "Usuario no encontrado";
}

} catch(Exception $e){

die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());



}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta poner esto al inicio

session_start();

solo debe ir

```
<?php
session_start();
```

... resto de codigo

Cuando escribes algo antes de enviar esto manda error :)

Prueba tambien

@session_start();

Te paso un fragmento del codigo que yo uso para ver si te funciona :)

```
if($_POST["funcion"]=="Get_Access"){
... aqui tu conexion a la BD
    foreach($result as $row){}
    if($row[0]!=""){
        echo true;
    }else{
        echo "Datos incorrectos.";
    }
exit();
}
```

y en Javascript

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "login.php",
data: ({
    funcion : "Get_Access",
    user : $("#user").val(),
    pass : $("#pass").val()
}),
dataType: "html",
async:false,
success: function(msg){
    if(msg==true){
        window.location="<?=$url?>/index.php";
    }else{
            alert("Error de datos");
        }
    }
});
```

Esto uso para conectarme

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
$resultado=$link->query($SQL);
```

Comment: Hola Rubén! Gracias por tu respuesta! pero yo solo quiero que inicie sesión si $usuario y $password es correcto. Por lo que no sé, si poner session_start(); al inicio es buena idea. No consigo ver la utilidad.

Comment: No hay que confundir el start session con tener sesión válida de usuario, @eva_mv